# Run code during installation or do something during downloading from google play

Tags: android

I need download some images from web (the app will use these images) before first run of the application. During installation or during downloading from Google Play. Is it possible?

I need to use logos in the first Activity, that are put on the web archives. I would not do it, but the app should work without internet connectivity and when I want to download an image during the app running, I will not download it without the internet connection. That´s why I am asking, how to do it another way?

Comment: What exactly do you want? And what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download these images on the first launch of your application. Everytime the application is openned, you need to check if the images are available (in the folder you downloaded them). If not, you need to download them. Be sure to let the user know what you are doing, and make them waiting while you download them.

Other solution would be to include them directly in the .apk (add them in drawables/raw folder, they're meant to be used this way)

Comment: I know about these solutions, so the answer is: "No there is no way how to download data during installation or dowloading from the store"?

Comment: the answer is No there's not, except if it's contained in the .apk already